# Как спарсить страницу, которая не сразу загружает все данные, на python?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup

Всем добрый день. Пишу парсер на Python, который парсит эту страницу https://www.flashscore.ru/match/6PN2l3Bc/#match-summary

(а именно время, в правом верхнем углу), но почему-то при запуске выводит None. Из-за чего это происходит? Может потому что код от страницы открывается в отдельном окне? P.S. Если нажать ctrl + shift + c, то откроется новое окно почему-то. Как спарсить время с этой страницы? https://www.flashscore.ru/match/6PN2l3Bc/#match-summary

Код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get('https://www.flashscore.ru/match/6PN2l3Bc/#match-summary')

    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    time = soup.find('div', class_="description__time mstat-date")

    print(time)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Вывод:

```
None
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если попробовать с requests спарсить, то выводит просто тег, но данные внутри тега он не видит:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)  # Получим метод Response
    r.encoding = 'utf8'
    return r.text  # Вернем данные объекта text


def get_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    head = soup.find('div', id='utime')
    print(head)


get_link(get_html('https://www.flashscore.ru/match/SvCBnstA/#match-summary'))
```

вывод:

```
<div class="description__time" id="utime"></div>
```

Comment: И выводит None с любым элементом на этой странице

Comment: обычно для веб-парсинга используется requests, а не selenium

Comment: @Александр, попробовал с requests, но выводит просто html тег, внутри пусто (изменил основной текст, посмотрите)

Comment: вы неправильно парсите, посмотрите на r.text, там всё ок

Comment: я бы вам рекомендовать изучить regex

Comment: import re .. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: да и в документация bs4 вам стоит заглянуть

Comment: @Александр, в r.text по прежнему нет данных о времени: `<div id="utime" class="description__time"></div>` но в нем должны быть данные: `<div id="utime" class="description__time">16.06.2020 21:30</div>`

Comment: я заметил, надо подумать

Comment: если посмотреть, то эти данные не сразу загружаются, сначала мы видим экран загрузки, поэтому и получается пустое значение.

Comment: @Александр, добавить time.sleep или с помощью селениума поставить ожидание?

Comment: @Александр, действительно, везде эта дичь из-за того, что долго грузится сайт: `<span>Loading...</span></div></div>` Как дождаться полной загрузки сайта?

Comment: похоже, что для такой задачи не подойдёт requests.

Comment: Видимо да, только селениум

Comment: да, возможно, сейчас помогу с ним, у меня есть идея

Comment: большое спасибо, жду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы просто неправильно распарсили.

Вот верный вариант:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get('https://www.flashscore.ru/match/6PN2l3Bc/#match-summary')

    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    time = soup.find('div', id="utime")

    print(time.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Поправка 1:

Заметка: здесь можно обойтись и только функционалом selenium-а.

В коде ниже, если после 30 секунд не появляется id="utime", selenium вызовет ошибку

```
from selenium import webdriver


def setup():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    return driver


def main(driver):
    driver.get("https://www.flashscore.ru/match/6PN2l3Bc/#match-summary")

    utime = driver.find_element_by_id("utime")

    return utime.text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = setup()
    time = main(driver)
    print(time)
```

Поправка 2:
добавил функцию, для ожидания нужного id, включающего нужный тест

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def main(sec_wait):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, sec_wait)

    driver.get("https://www.flashscore.ru/match/6PN2l3Bc/#match-summary")

    time = wait_to_find_id(driver, wait, "utime", ".")

    print(time)


def wait_to_find_id(driver, wait, id_, text_to_find=""):
    """Finds an element by id and an expectation for
    checking if the given text is present in the specified element.
    If no match was found within the specified time, an Exception is raised.
    """
    try:
        element = wait.until(
            EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, id_), text_to_find)
        )
        return driver.find_element_by_id(id_).text
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.quit()
        raise Exception(f"Element not found after {wait._timeout} sec of waiting")
    except Exception as e:
        driver.quit()
        raise e


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(10)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109466/discussion-on-answer-by-------python).